# Как получить список названия папок и сделать файлы в каждой папке согласно названию папки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Народ, имеется код, который создает папки в директории через цикл. см.код.

```
import os

#Директория, где надо создать папки
path = 'c:\\Users\\Python\\python_learning\\tasks\\lessons'
#название папки для создания
projectname = "les_"
#Меняем директорию на path
chdir = os.chdir(path)
#Проверяю текущую директорию, нужно сделать правильную проверку директории через If
cur_dir = os.getcwd()

#Делаем функцию на создание папок, типа les_1, les_2 до les_55, через цикл.
def create_folder():
    for i in range(1,56):  #делаем цикл до 55
        #print (i) # смотрим цикл
        os.mkdir(projectname + str(i)) #создаем папки

#вызываем функцию 
create_folder()
```

Хочу сделать еще такую функцию, чтобы она прочитала все названия папок в директории, а это от les_1 до les_55, и чтобы зайдя в каждую папку, например les_25, внутри лежал файл с названием les_25.py . 
Подскажите, посредством чего можно это реализовать?

Comment: Создать файл можно командами ``f = open(filename,"w")``, ``f.close()``. Дальше сам по аналогии.

Comment: `dir_name = projectname + str(i)` `open(dir_name + "/" + dir_name + ".py", 'w')`

Comment: Спасибо за решение данной задачи

Answer (score 1):

будет универсально работать под Win и Linux

```
#Делаем функцию на создание папок, типа les_1, les_2 до les_55, через цикл.
def create_folder():
    for i in range(1,56):  #делаем цикл до 55
        #print (i) # смотрим цикл
        name = projectname + str(i)
        os.mkdir(name) #создаем папки
        with open(os.path.join(name, name + '.py'), 'w') as f:
            pass
```